# RSA-OEP encryption in ie11

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, internet-explorer-11, webcrypto-api

I have been unable to find any examples of RSA-OAEP encryption in IE11.

Here's a snippet of my implementation, in which I am given a very vague error.

```js
function convertStringToArrayBufferView(str) {
      var bytes = new Uint8Array(str.length);
      for (var iii = 0; iii < str.length; iii++) {
        bytes[iii] = str.charCodeAt(iii);
      }

      return bytes;
    }

    
    var crypto = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;
    var config = {
      name: 'RSA-OAEP',
      modulusLength: 2048,
      publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
      hash: {
        name: 'SHA-256'
      }
    };

    var keyOp = crypto.subtle.generateKey(config, false, ['encrypt', 'decrypt']);
    keyOp.onerror = function(e) {
      console.error(e);
    };
    keyOp.oncomplete = function(e) {
      encrypt(e.target.result);
    };

    function encrypt(keypair) {
      var data = "abc1234444"

      var encOp = crypto.subtle.encrypt({
        name: config.name,
        iv: config.iv || crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16)),
        key: keypair.publicKey
      }, keypair.publicKey, convertStringToArrayBufferView(data));

      encOp.onerror = function(e) {
        console.error(e);
      };
      encOp.oncomplete = function(e) {
        console.log({
          data: new Uint8Array(e.target.result)
        });
      };
    }
```

When I change the algorithm to RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5, everything works flawlessly

```js
    function convertStringToArrayBufferView(str) {
      var bytes = new Uint8Array(str.length);
      for (var iii = 0; iii < str.length; iii++) {
        bytes[iii] = str.charCodeAt(iii);
      }

      return bytes;
    }

    
    var crypto = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;
    var config = {
      name: 'RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5',
      modulusLength: 2048,
      publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
      hash: {
        name: 'SHA-256'
      }
    };

    var keyOp = crypto.subtle.generateKey(config, false, ['encrypt', 'decrypt']);
    keyOp.onerror = function(e) {
      console.error(e);
    };
    keyOp.oncomplete = function(e) {
      encrypt(e.target.result);
    };

    function encrypt(keypair) {
      var data = "abc1234444"

      var encOp = crypto.subtle.encrypt({
        name: config.name,
        iv: config.iv || crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16)),
        key: keypair.publicKey
      }, keypair.publicKey, convertStringToArrayBufferView(data));

      encOp.onerror = function(e) {
        console.error(e);
      };
      encOp.oncomplete = function(e) {
        console.log({
          data: new Uint8Array(e.target.result)
        });
      };
    }
```

Comment: You're being pretty vague about the *vague error*. What is it?

Comment: **Error**. If I dig a little deeper into the object then I'll find an **Unable to get property 'message' of undefined or null reference** message but I'm not convinced that has anything to do with the issue here.  Please let me know if you're not having the same issue in IE11 when you run the code snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

This problem looks similar to [Public key encryption in Internet Explorer 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047314/public-key-encryption-in-internet-explorer-11)

There, [@fenghuang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5428388/fenghuang) needed "to add the hash field when invoking the encrypt call"

```
    var encOp = cryptoSubtle.encrypt(
        {
            name: "RSA-OAEP",
            hash: { name: "SHA-256" }
        },
        key.publicKey,
        data
    );
```